# Dehumidifer outside to dry inside

Tags: water, basement

I live in a tiny place. I recently found a dehumidifier that could be placed outside. It has sensors that can be placed inside and connect to the dehumidifier.

Does it make sense to put the dehumidifier outside (so it will suck outside potentially humid air) and send the dry air into my place through a ventilation pipe ? Will this actually dry my place, as opposed to placing the dehumidifier inside ?

[The dehumidifier](https://detail.tmall.com/item.htm?id=520488111370&ali_refid=a3_420434_1006:1110506873:N:%E5%B7%A5%E4%B8%9A%E9%99%A4%E6%B9%BF%E6%9C%BA:a3d48892527fc20f15e42a13c21d3ea3&ali_trackid=1_a3d48892527fc20f15e42a13c21d3ea3&spm=a230r.1.0.0.KKNrdO) sorry I could not find the description in english.

Comment: This design makes no sense to me, but maybe someone else can justify it...

Comment: Can you post the make/model of the dehumidifier such that the experts here can make sense of how the unit works?

Comment: The device does not appear weather proof. It is more likely that they mean it can be placed outside of the room it is feeding dry air to. If you have a passage that states otherwise, please include it even if it is not in english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is fairly broad without device information, but the theory is sound. You essentially pressurize your home with dry dehumidifier exhaust to expel humid interior air. This depends, of course, on your home not being perfectly sealed. This isn't a problem as no home is.

The challenge will be ducting the air into your home in such a way as to not create new leaks that will negate the benefit of the dehumidifier.